# Whitelist Apps That Use Data

Tags: root-access, to-do-list

I only use the map application while driving and therefore would like only for this application to be used while driving.  Can I define a whitelist instead of manually going through on my apps and essentially creating a blacklist of which apps can be used.  This gets particularly annoying when I install new applications also.  Can this be done with root maybe?  I have Nexus 5 rooted running Lineage OS 7.1.  [Found this](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/33jml8/how_do_i_whitelist_mobile_data_usage/) couldn't get the 1st app to work and the 2nd app wasn't truly a whitelist.

Comment: You mean to say NoRootFirewall was not working. But Afwall+ and Norootfireball are good applications.

Comment: Try [Donkeyguard](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-donkeyguard-security-management-t2831556)

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar no I couldn't get Afwall+ to work.  No RootFirewall worked but isn't a whitelist technically you have to check everything which is annoying.  Noroot Firewall is a blacklist.  Not to mention you have to restart on reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have given up on finding a solely white list application.

NoRootFirewall does work but isn't truly a whitelist.